# when viewing a page in firebug, can I see which event fires when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

I'm viewing a page, and want to know which event is fired when I click on a button, and I want to trace through the .js files to help me learn what is going on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

When you have the script panel enabled, you can click the pause button on the left to stop all JavaScript interaction. When you then press the button it stops and you can use the debugger to step through the code.